# How to automatically change woocommerce processing status to completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status

How to change in `woocommerce` order status from processing to completed
?

I found snippet, but it only changes status if you go to thank you page, but if my customer decides just to close `paypal` page and don't go to thank you page ?

Then it is still processing, tested it already. I need automatically to detect processing status and change it to processing.

Comment: Can you narrow your question down? It's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

This will check for when the order changes status. If the status changes to processing, it will set the status to completed. Note that it does go through processing, so the user will probably get two emails back to back. You can disable one of the emails in the WC settings dashboard.

```
function wc_status_change($order_id,$old_status,$new_status) {
   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   if($order->status == 'processing'){
       $order->update_status('completed');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have two options the first may not work as it is related to previous versions of woocommerce but the second one should work

add the code to your functions.php

**1º**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'update_order_status_woo', 10, 2 );
function update_order_status_woo( $order_status, $order_id ) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if ( $order_status == 'processing' && ( 'on-hold' == $order->status || 'pending' == $order->status || 'failed' == $order->status ) ) {
        return 'completed';
    }
    return $order_status;
}
```

**2º**

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'auto_update_processing_to_complete');

function auto_update_processing_to_complete($order_id)
{
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    if ($order->data['status'] == 'processing') {
        $order->update_status( 'completed' );
    }   
}
```